# Unable to access .resx file from Windows 8.1 Runtime windows store app project

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps, resourcebundle

I am developing **Windows Phone 8.1(WinRT) windows store app** project. I have developed different PCL project for DataConnection, ServiceConnection etc...which I am referencing in WP 8.1 project. In DataConnection pcl I have all .resx files which were created under .net 4.0 target. All my PCL projects were created in Xamarin Studio for cross platform(Android, iOS, WP). Now  I opened my project in **Visual Studio Premium 2013** in-order to develop WP project and changed my target framework from .net 4.0 to 4.5, since WP 8.1 requires 4.5 as target.

After changing, I am unable to read string resources values from Windows Phone project. While executing below line,

```
string test = Test.String1;
```

It throws exception as,

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Value cannot be null.
```

Exception Trace:

```
System.ArgumentNullException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: format
  Source=mscorlib
  ParamName=format
  StackTrace:
       at System.String.Format(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args)
       at System.Environment.GetResourceString(String key, Object[] values)
       at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(String name, CultureInfo culture)
       at App.Core.Resources.Test.get_String1()
       at App.Forms.WindowsPhoneUI.MainPage..ctor()
       at App.Forms.WindowsPhoneUI.App_Forms_WindowsPhoneUI_XamlTypeInfo.XamlTypeInfoProvider.Activate_4_MainPage()
       at App.Forms.WindowsPhoneUI.App_Forms_WindowsPhoneUI_XamlTypeInfo.XamlUserType.ActivateInstance()
  InnerException:
```

Screenshot:

[image]

What is going wrong here? Please someone help me to fix this.

Comment: check if your Test object isn't null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/philliphoff/archive/2014/11/19/missingmanifestresourceexception-when-using-portable-class-libraries-in-winrt.aspx) blog helped me to fix this issue. Although the exceptions were different, in the blog its mentioned as MissingManifestResourceException whereas I was getting ArgumentNull exception, but internal it was crashing in Getstring method in both the cases.

Code Referred from above blog:

I added below class in my project.

```
public class WindowsRuntimeResourceManager : ResourceManager
{

  private readonly ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

  private WindowsRuntimeResourceManager(string baseName, Assembly assembly) : base(baseName, assembly)
  {
    this.resourceLoader = ResourceLoader.GetForViewIndependentUse(baseName);
  }

  public static void InjectIntoResxGeneratedApplicationResourcesClass(Type resxGeneratedApplicationResourcesClass)
  {
    resxGeneratedApplicationResourcesClass.GetRuntimeFields()
      .First(m => m.Name == "resourceMan")
      .SetValue(null, new WindowsRuntimeResourceManager(resxGeneratedApplicationResourcesClass.FullName, resxGeneratedApplicationResourcesClass.GetTypeInfo().Assembly));
  }



  public override string GetString(string name, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    return this.resourceLoader.GetString(name);
  }
}
```

And in Windows Phone project before calling resource file, just have to call below method.

```
WindowsRuntimeResourceManager.InjectIntoResxGeneratedApplicationResourcesClass(typeof(App.Resources.Account));

            string test = App.Resources.Account.Error_CouldnotCreateUserProfile;
```